# Mobile CSS Bar in landscape doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have CSS bars, instead of links, on my mobile web page. It works fine in portraits but defaults to to links in landscape view. I use a little bit of jQuery to do this but I can't figure out why it doesn't work in landscape. I simplified the code to force it to work but that didn't help. Could someone help me with this. The jQuery code is below.

```
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 600) 
{ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#header ul').addClass('show'); 
    }); 
}
else
{
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#header ul').addClass('show');
}
```

Comment: You code doesn't make sense at all. You are doing the same thing on each side of the if/else.

Comment: Also...you should really use a `$(window).resize()` function to check portrait v.s. landscape views.

Answer (score 0):

u cannot use document.ready function inside an if-else construct.

$(document).ready(function() is called as soon as the dom is ready or all your page elements are created. you should indeed do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 600) { 
    $('#header ul').addClass('show'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Even though your code is better written, the code from the OP will work (even though it doesn't make sense and some braces are missing). You can open multiple document ready calls - whether this is useful or not.

Comment: but jQuery bundles it all into one and execute it.

Comment: Yeah, true, but one of an `if-else`-clause will never be added.

Comment: You said, that you cannot use com ready within an `if-else`-clause. But actually you could: http://jsfiddle.net/XLm7u/ - or maybe I'm getting you wrong. ;)